# Break into debugger after next mouse click

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

When debugging a c# WPF application, is there a way to jump into the debugger immediately after the next mouse click?

Suppose I want to debug what happens when a certain button is pressed.

I can of course figure out what method is executed when the button is pressed, by analyzing the code and resource files, and then set a breakpoint at the start of this method. If I am not familiar with the code, this can take some time to figure out.

However it would be far easier and quicker if I could tell Visual Studio something like:
*"Break execution, the next time user code is executed on the gui thread, **after** the next mouse click"*

I.e. something like the "Break all" command (ctrl+alt+break), which does not break immediately, but waits for me to click the button and then break.

Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio?

Comment: Back when I was doing winforms stuff what I would do is do a break all then do a "step into", this would let the program run till I hit user code again. I don't know if this trick works with WPF.

Comment: Unfortunately at least with the wpf app I am currently dealing with, this does not work.It Is a MVVM app, and when I click "step into", VS immediatelly jumps into the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event handler, which calls all the `CanExecute()` methods for each `RelayCommand`.

Comment: put a [`[DebuggerNonUserCode]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggernonusercodeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) above the `CanExecute`, that will make the debugger ignore it temporaraly.

Comment: It works, sort of :) Turns out that a lot of CanExecute calls were implemented as anonymous lambdas (so no way to add the attribute), and there were a couple MouseOver events as well. But after removing all of the lambdas, and decorating the rest with [DebuggerNonUserCode], this trick works. So this is not as simple as I hoped, but it is something to keep in mind. Still hoping that there is a way that works with less code changes.